# Error attempting to run pip3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Can anyone advise why I'm getting this error? Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS

```
ubuntu@main:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Here are some relevant outputs if it helps:

```
ubuntu@main:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.4
ubuntu@main:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
ubuntu@main:~$ pip --version
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
ubuntu@main:~$
```

Comment: try `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.9-distutils`

Answer (score 1):

1. try reinstall pip:

   sudo apt remove python3-pip

   sync

   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

   sudo apt install python3-pip
2. It's just a warning message. if u don't want to see them use '-W' key to avoid warnings:

   python -W --version